# How to highlight data in an Excel table/graph based on previous values?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

Is there a way in Excel to highlight data based on a condition on the previous values? To be more precise, would there be a way to tell Excel: "Higlight this cell `c` if the value of the preceding one `c-1` is lower than the value of the cell before it `c-2` and that the value of `c` is lower than the value of `c-1`."?

When I say highlight, it would be to make the cell `c` and `c-1` of a different background color and on a line graph the section corresponding of a different line color.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, what you are looking for is called **conditional formatting**. It is available both in Excel and in other spread sheet applications e.g. OpenOffice Calc/LibreOffice Calc.

You can use this to let the formatting of a cell (e.g. the background color or text color) depend on the value of the cell.

I'm not sure if it can depend on the value of a different cell, but perhaps you could calculate the difference in a dedicated cell and highlight that one.

Further reading here: [Use conditional formatting to highlight information](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-conditional-formatting-to-highlight-information-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f)

Comment: Thank you for your response! I know about conditional formatting but I don't know how to use it to fit my specific need, any idea?